# chefspec testing for stray ruby variable

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

Over here I am returning status of provider in variable, how can I mock that status in chefspec for testing ?

```
ret = yum_package 'blah' do
   action :install
end   
cookbook_file "/etc/init.d/blah" do
   source "blah"
   only_if { ret.updated_by_last_action? }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this work, the `ret.update_by_last_action?` is evaluated at compile time when the provider didn't run.

The recommended way to do this would be to use [notifications](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifications) like this:

```rb
yum_package 'blah' do
   action :install
   notifies :create,"cookbook_file[/etc/init.d/blah]", :immediately
end   

cookbook_file "/etc/init.d/blah" do
   action :nothing
   source "blah"
end
```

And then you can expect the [notification is sent](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#notify) and that the file is created.

Spec example:

```rb
blah_package = chef_run.yup_package('blah')
expect(blah_package).to notify('cookbook_file[/etc/init.d/blah]').to(:create).immediately
expect(chef_run).to render_file('/etc/init.d/blah')
```